# How to stop a batch file altogether from a child batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have a couple of batch files. One is the parent and others are children that are called by the parent.

Let's say I have `Deploy.bat` that calls `ExtractParameters.bat`.

In `ExtractParameters.bat` I want to be able to stop the entire process.

If I use `exit /b` the rest of the `Deploy.bat` would be executed.

If I use `exit` then the `Deploy.bat` is also stopped, but my command line window is also closed.

What I want is to keep my command line window open, but stop the parent script from child script.

What can I do?

Comment: Not sure this is possible. I probably would launch the parent batchfile in a new window, so it doesn't matter if its killed or not. (`start batchfile.bat`)

Comment: One possible workaround is having the child batch file change a variable when it's done, that the parent batch reads in a loop (for example every minute).

Answer (score 1):

Commonly, the [exit code](https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/batch-file-errorlevels.html) of a child script is examined in the parent, and, if the error level shows a fault, the parent can interrupt processing, or go to fault-handling code (not what I'd term true exception handling, but likely good enough, from your description).

Comment: I would recommend getting UnxUtils btw, this greatly expands what you can do in simple batch files: https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/